# Sign HmacSHA256 - is algorithm irrelevant?

Tags: java, cryptography, java-security

Why does this always work regardless of the second parameter of `SecretKeySpec`? shouldn't it be a valid algorithm name? thanks

```
Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "it does not matter what I put here. why?");
sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
```

the question is: why the thing that I pass is irrelevant? the code always works properly regardless of what I pass as second argument (the algorithm name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this is just a coincidence because Java Cryptographic Architecture is based on the concept of [providers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html). It looks like the default JDK providers for `Mac` don't check the algorithm from `SecretKeySpec` and depend entirely on the  algorithm saved in `Mac.algorithm` field.

You still should set the right algorithm in `SecretKeySpec` because nothing stops a provider to check the key's algorithm. For example if you look at `Mac.chooseProvider(Key key, AlgorithmParameterSpec params)` private method it passes the key to external code:

```
// if provider says it does not support this key, ignore it
if (s.supportsParameter(key) == false) {
    continue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code you will see that

```
 public SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm) {
      ...
      this.algorithm = algorithm;
```

and on the header

```
@throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the key data or the algorithm name is null or if the key
     *             data is empty.
```

So `SecretKeySpec` don't care the algorithm.

And when you init the MAC you will get error only

```
 * @exception InvalidKeyException if the given key is inappropriate for
 * initializing this MAC.
 public final void init(Key key) throws InvalidKeyException {
```